# Using ComponentStyles using @fluentui/react-northstar

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluentui-react

I am trying to give all the `<Segment>`s in my project a border radius. From reading the [docs](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.63.0/theming-examples#theme-level-styling) it seems the best way to do this is the componentStyles in a custom theme.

I have imported `teamsTheme` from northstar, created a custom theme, adding a Segment property and merged using a `deepmerge` package. I used [this](https://dev.to/pearlzsquare/fluent-uireact-northstar-theming-and-component-styling-mlk) post as a jumping off point.

The end result is all base styles of the segment component are lost and only the styles I put in used. What have I missed so that my changes are merged with the segment component styling rather than overriding them.

Cheers.

**Code example**

```js
import { teamsTheme, Provider } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
import deepMerge from "deepmerge";


const customTheme = {
    componentStyles: {
        Segment: {
            root: { // Added root here from trial and error. Nothing else seemed to make any changes
                borderRadius: 4
            }
        }
    },
};

const theme = deepMerge(teamsTheme, customTheme);

const App () => {

    return <Provider theme={theme}>
        <Segment>Test</Segment>
    </Provider>
}
```

Comment: have you import the teamsTheme like import {
  Provider,
  teamsTheme,
} from '@fluentui/react-northstar';

Comment: Hi @Sayali-MSFT - It is the first line of the example, unless I misunderstand what you mean

Comment: Are you import the teamsTheme?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, he has, it is at the top of the code example. Any further advice on this matter? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Please have look into this thread-https://github.com/webdriverio/cucumber-boilerplate/issues/1
hope it's helpful.

Comment: The documentation you linked is for cucumber and is the opposite of what is happening in my question. This is not helpful

Comment: Hello @Ghojzilla - Can you please try it using this code ?

// Merging my custom theme with the preset teamsTheme
const theme = deepMerge(teamsTheme, customTheme);
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext(theme);

function ThemeProvider({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <Provider theme={theme}>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
    </Provider>
  );
};

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution when I tried [creating a custom component](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.63.0/integrate-custom-components)

```js
const customTheme = {
    siteVariables: {
        boxShadow: "0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
    },
    componentStyles: {
        Segment: {
            root: ({ variables, theme: { siteVariables } }) => ({
                ...teamsTheme.componentVariables.Segment(siteVariables),
                borderRadius: "4px",
                borderWidth: 0,

            })
        }
    }
};

const theme = deepMerge(teamsTheme, customTheme);

/// Unrelated code  removed 

return <Provider theme={theme}> ... </Provider>
```

Here I can update the border radius and the box shadow of all `Segment`s. Maybe the better solution was to use a custom `StyledSegment` instead of updating the existing but this solution will work for now.